# Prove that $((B \rightarrow C) \wedge A) \rightarrow ((A' \vee C') \rightarrow B')$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to prove $((B \rightarrow C) \wedge A) \rightarrow ((\bar{A} \vee \bar{C}) \rightarrow \bar{B})$ using [rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Table:_Rules_of_Inference)?

I know the first step is to assume the left side is true, but I'm not sure which rules of inference to start with. Any hints?

Comment: How do you parenthesize that formula? Does $\land$ bind tighter than $\to$? Which way does $\to$ associate? Do the primes stand for negation?

Comment: I added parenthesis. The primes do stand for negation.

Comment: And can you use any rule of inference that appear in Wikipedia's collection of such rules?

Comment: Yes, you would use any rules that appear in the table.

Comment: After you assume the LHS, you can further assume $A' \vee C'$ leaving only $B'$ to prove. You can apply Simplification to the conjunction and then Material implication to the implication $B \rightarrow C$ and I think you'll have something to work with then.

Comment: Replacing $p\to q$ by $\lnot p\lor q$ a few times allows to prove the implication.